Labels show as "undefined" when they are generated using a formula
I have a CSV layer, and the Labels for each marker is generated using the Concat function. On the QGIS Map they show fine, but on the exported QGIS2Web Map they show "undefined"
The label uses the "Concat" function to derive its content.
Concat("FleetName", ' ',"kph",'kph')
If the Concat function is NOT used, and instead a single field is chosen it displays fine in both places.
How can I make the labels in the QGIS2Web view show the same as the QGIS Map?
QGIS Map

Exported Map


I’m voting to close this question because there is no question.

In your layer create a new field and with the calculator populate the field with "field1" + "field2".  Then use the single labels on this new field.

@andreaordonselli thankyou! that worked.. if you post an answer I'll go ahead and accept it. Thank you for taking the time to provide that, much appreciated.

There's no need. For these simple things it would be better to open an issue on github and refer to gis.stack for more complex things. Kindly consider donating a virtual coffee to support the development of the project via the button on the home page on github. Thank you.

@andreaordonselli: I will have some questions about qgis2opengis in the near future: Which ones do I post here and which ones on github? This is not completely clear to me.

You choose where to post your question, I recommend using Github first and Stack for problems that cannot be resolved on Github.
